# jQuery - receiving the $_FILES array using $.post

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I am attempting to submit a form via jQuery. My form contains fields and a file that must be uploaded. It is of type `ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"`.

I can receive all my field values using: `post = $('#myForm').serialize();`
But how do I receive the `$_FILES` array? I need this to process the uploaded file.

Is this possible using jQuery, and if so how? Or do I need to use a special upload plugin for jQuery?

Answer (score 12):

jquery form is the best way to do it,
you can add it to any normal form,

```
<form method="post" action="URL">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="text" name"text">
<input type="submit"> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(form).ajaxForm();
})
</script>
```

will work as expected, but with ajax.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples

Answer (score 11):

You cannot upload files through javascript.

Check out this related question:
  [Is it possible to use Ajax to do file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543926/is-it-possible-to-ajax-a-file-upload/543927#543927)

Essentially, the two most popular ways of "faking" AJAX for file uploads is using a Flash plugin such as [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/) or submitting the form to a hidden iframe that processes the request.

Answer (score 1):

Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and enctype=multipart/form-data on the form. The file will not be sent

Answer (score 1):

Use FormData

```
<form>
<label for="imageToSend">Cargar imagen a la galeria</label>
<input type="file" name="imageToSend" id="imageToSend" value="Cargar imagen" />
</form>
<script>
$('#imageToSend').on('change',function(event){
    var dialog = $('#dialog');
    var Data = new FormData();
    Data.append('imageToSend',$('#imageToSend')[0].files);
    $(this).val('');//Clear input file
    $.ajax({
        url: "/upload",
        data: Data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type:'POST',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.success){
                //success handler   
            }else if(!data.success){
                //error backend handler
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            //error handler Ej:404 status
        }
    })
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the environment, like, say, you're writing an admin app for an intranet in which you recommend the browser, then real AJAX file uploads are possible with Firefox 3 and above. In all other cases, the iframe workaround or a Flash based uploader is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but not working in Google Chrome )
Look!

```
...
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="file" id="imf" name="imf"/>
<input type="button" id="Save"/>
</form>

...

$("#Save").live("click", function(){

var photo = document.getElementById("imf"); 
var file  = photo.files[0];

   $.post('/user/saveNewPhoto', {'imf':file.getAsDataURL(), fname:file.fileName }, function( data ){
   alert ( data );
    });

});
```

upload side script
need decode base64 ) and that is all
but i don't test this script on big size file