# Ajax(jQuery) strange file post problem

Tags: ajax, file, post, file-upload

I have a problem posting file via ajax jQuery function. I have something like this:

```
$('#my_form').submit(function() {
       var serialized = $(this).formSerialize();
       var sUrl = "xxx";

       $.ajax({
           url: sUrl,
           type: "POST",
           data: serialized,
           success: function(data) {
               $(".main_container").html(data);
           }
       })
       return false; // THIS return statment blocks sending file content
    });
```

When I remove **return false** statement everything is okey, server side gets the file content and etc, but when it's there (i monitor with firebug) that this posting sends only file name. What can be wrong?

P.S. - I need this return false statement, because I want to manipulate return data myself.

Comment: I think you forgot a semicolon after the `$.ajax({})`

Comment: Bad practice, but not a problem in this case. JS does do semi-colon insertion.

Comment: I know that it's a bad practise. Just missed it writing here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First stop — the manual.

> Data from file select elements is not serialized.

From http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

You can't read local files with JS, so you can't submit them using XMLHttpRequest.

[jQuery - receiving the $_FILES array using $.post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551627/jquery-receiving-the-files-array-using-post) lists a number of alternative approaches.