# How to make "webmail"-like file attaching/uploading

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, uploading

I want to implement file uploading with behaviour which is commonly seen in various kinds of webmail interfaces. I mean here that attachment (one or more) are selected by open file dialog and then their names are apearing under (for example) text area with body of message. And there is only info that attachment is added and it be uploaded when form is submitted.
I know it would include AJAX maybe some server side scripts, but I have completly no idea where and how search examples of such kind of mechanism.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [is-it-possible-to-ajax-a-file-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543926/is-it-possible-to-ajax-a-file-upload).

Standard browser + Javascript is not enough, extra help is needed. A combination of browser plugin like `flash` and server-side support. Look for a solution within the web frameworks that the application is using (or considering).

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is not a requirement, neither is Javascript. Only a form with an `<input type="file">`. Your server has to process the result though which obviously depends on the language you're using.

Comment: yes, but I mean one or multiple files and upload only when upload connected form (with other fields than only upload) is submitted

Comment: Just use JS to add more file inputs as files are added.