# Issue uploading a file via ajax using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, file-upload

*Before starting, note that I have to update a website that is not mine, so I can't redo the whole logic. If I were to do this I would do it differently.*

I have a cakephp application with a form with a lot of fields. In this form you can browse for a file and save it asynchronously. Here is how it's done:

```
<input type="file" name="data[FileUpload][file]" id="myFileToUpload">
<a id="pickFile" href="#">Upload&nbsp;Now</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#pickFile').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post(
            "/admin/FileUploads/saveFromFlash/<?php e($session->id()) ?>", {
            data: $("#myFileToUpload").val()
        }, function (data) {
            $("#returnedContentFromAjax").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
            "json");
    });
</script>
```

The function called mainly does this:

```
$this->FileUpload->save($this->data)
```

but this always returns false and "No upload passed". Here is the line creating the error message:

```
if (!isset($this->data['FileUpload']['file'])) {
        $this->setUploadError('No upload passed');
    return false;
}
```

I have no clue how to send this "$this->data['FileUpload']['file']" via ajax...  I guess this is the key problem since I don't know what object to pass here:

```
{ data:$("#myFileToUpload").val() },
```

I've been on it all evening, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: #myFileToUpload is a INPUT type="FILE" element?  you can't access the contents of the file from javascript.  Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543926/is-it-possible-to-ajax-a-file-upload

Comment: argh... well it's the end for me ^^ thanks for the answer

Comment: Could I use the form plugin even if the file upload is in another form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In summary: javascript can't access the contents of a file selected for upload.

This article deals with getting an "ajax effect" for your file uploads: [Is it possible to use Ajax to do file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543926/is-it-possible-to-ajax-a-file-upload)

Comment: is it possible to use something like jquery form even if the uploader is already in a form?

Comment: Yes, jquery Form will grab the action of your existing form and post to that.  There an example for file upload in the code samples: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples

Answer (score 0):

try uploadify, it is JQuery Ajax uploading system. Easy to use.
http://www.uploadify.com/