# jQuery Single File Upload using HTML Input within a Dialog Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, upload

Is there a simple way to upload a single file through HTML input type file with [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)'s dialog box using `$.post`?

Hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used ui.dialog and [ajaxfileupload](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/)

hth

Answer (score 3):

**Read this before start!**

> - [Is it possible to use Ajax to do file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543926/is-it-possible-to-ajax-a-file-upload/543927#543927)

*then you can go through theese links:*

> - http://www.uploadify.com/
> - http://valums.com/ajax-upload/
> - http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score -1):

You have many choices, the easiest is probably just using jQuery to control a form that submits to an iframe.

Alternatives include [Flash](http://swfupload.org/), Java, Gears, Silverlight, and HTML5 uploaders.

http://www.appelsiini.net/2009/10/drag-and-drop-file-upload-with-google-gears

http://www.plupload.com/