# Is it possible to pop open the upload file dialog without requiring the user to press Browse?

Tags: javascript

I think I've seen Gmail do it in Chrome or Internet Explorer, but I've never seen it in Firefox. I thought I'd ask anyways. Is it possible to do a file upload without requiring an `<input type="file" />`? I see that you can [use iframes to automatically submit the file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543926/is-it-possible-to-ajax-a-file-upload), so my question is

Can you programmatically pop up a file upload dialog?

If so, what browsers is it supported on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMail uses Flash to trigger the Browse File dialog.

You should be able to accomplish this with the [`FileReference`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html) class and its [`browse`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse()) method.

Also check out existing solutions, such as the [Uploadify Plugin](http://www.uploadify.com/).