# Issue with AJAX Upload Script in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I found this ajax file upload script here http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/

Which is supposed to add ajax functionality to my file upload form

```
<div id="dialog" title="Upload Image">
           <%
            Html.BeginForm("Upload", "BugTracker", FormMethod.Post,new { id="uploadForm",  enctype = "multipart/form-data"});
           %>

                Select a file: <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />   
                <h6>Upload a screenshot related to the ticket</h6>
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Upload" id="upload" onclick="uploadImage();" name="submit" />


            <%Html.EndForm();%>
</div>
```

And I have set up a function to be called when my upload form is submitted like so:

```
function uploadImage() {

    var action = $("#uploadForm").attr('action');

    $.ajaxFileUpload({
        url: action,
        secureuri: false,
        fileElementId: 'file',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status) {
            $("#RelatedFileName").val() = data.FileName;
            $("#dialog").dialog("close");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

but it is skipping right over the success callback function, and the browser asks if I would like to download the json file. Here's a peek at my upload action:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            Regex imageFilenameRegex = new Regex(@"(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$");
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (!imageFilenameRegex.IsMatch(file.FileName))
                {
                    return JavaScript("alert('invalid file. you must upload a jpg, jpeg, png, or gif');");
                }
                else
                {
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                    file.SaveAs(filePath);

                    return Json(new { FileName = "/Uploads/" + file.FileName });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return JavaScript("alert('seriously? select a file to upload before hitting the upload button.');");
            }
        }
```

I've used jQuery.post and it will hit the controller action but file will be null, but at least errors would pop up in their alert boxes, so that is why I sought out another option. Now it hits the controller action and the file gets uploaded, but it isn't handling any response. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin you are using expects `text/html` as response Content Type even if you are passing JSON. So if you really want to use it you need to do this:

```
return Content("{ FileName: '/Uploads/' }", "text/html");
```

As you understand that's crap.

So go ahead and download the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). It's much easier to use. You don't have to do anything in your HTML, it's totally unobtrusive. Just leave the form as is and in javascript simply:

```
$(function() {
    // Only indicate the form id, it will take care of reading the form action, 
    // returning false, ..., all you need is to concentrate 
    // on the success callback
    $('#uploadForm').ajaxForm(function(result) {
        alert(result);
    });
});
```

Also notice that in case of error you shouldn't return Javascript. You always need to return Json from your controller action. So in case of error:

```
return Json(new { errorMessage = "Kaboom", fileName = "" });
```

and in case of success:

```
return Json(new { errorMessage = "", fileName = "/Uploads/" + file.FileName });
```

so now you can check whether there's an error by inspecting the `errorMessage` property on the returned JSON object:

```
$('#uploadForm').ajaxForm(function(result) {
    if (result.errorMessage != '') {
        alert(result.errorMessage);
    } else {
        $('#RelatedFileName').val(result.fileName);
        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do ajax uploads, you are going to want do the upload form inside an iframe.

See: http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

Comment: I use a multiple-file ajax-based upload elsewhere in my project and it works great without your iFrames. I would prefer to get this success callback working, because the upload portion itself is working fine.

Comment: The only way to do it without an iFrame is using flash AFAIK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543926/is-it-possible-to-ajax-a-file-upload

Comment: I just looked through the script - this one rebuilds my form with an iframe and then does the upload. So...any ideas on the callback?

Comment: I think that plugin is expecting the return value to be text, have you tried simply returning the results as XML or text (not json)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to set the content type here as well:

```
return Json(new { FileName = "/Uploads/filename.ext" }, "text/html", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```