# Async upload problem using jquery.form.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload, asynchronous

I'm using the jquery.form plugin to asynchronously upload documents in an MVC project.

Taking my lead from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983326/problem-with-ajax-upload-script-and-mvc2) previous answer, here's what I have on the page:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "JobFile", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "uploadForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) %>
<% { %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary() %>

    <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />
    <input type="text" id="RelatedFileName" />

<% } %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#uploadForm').ajaxForm(function (result) {
            if (result.errorMessage != '') {
                alert(result.errorMessage);
            } else {
                $('#RelatedFileName').val(result.fileName);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that when the page loads I get the following javascript error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'ajaxForm'

This error is found on the line containing

```
$('#uploadForm').ajaxForm(function (result) {
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Just an FYI, `/Scripts/jquery.form.js` will work the same (if not more consistently) as `../../Scripts/jquery.form.js` - both start at the site root.

Answer (score 4):

Check that jquery isn't being included in the page twice.

Comment: Thanks a million.! After breakin my head over it for hours and hours, this was the solution,

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method that I am using for MVC3, CodeIgniter and Yii.
One important this is that your should specify **method="post"**, **enctype** and **encoding="multipart/form-data"**

```
var submitForm = function(_formId){
var _genMsg = $('#genMsg');
_submitForm = $('form').index($('#'+_formId));
if(subCommonForm(_submitForm, 'main')){
    _genMsg.attr('class', 'information-box round');
    _genMsg.html('Saving...');
    $('#'+_formId).ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            _genMsg.attr('class', 'information-box round');

            data.code == 0
                ? _genMsg.attr('class', 'confirmation-box round')
                : _genMsg.attr('class', 'error-box round');

            _genMsg.html(data.message);
            _genMsg.fadeIn();
        }
    });

    $('#'+_formId).submit();
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Is 'uploadForm' the id of your `<form>` object? If it is then you may wan to check in something like FireBug to make sure your plug-in is included on your page properly.

Comment: Yes, 'uploadForm' is the ID of my form. The downloaded source is "<form action="/JobFile/Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm" method="post">". If I use the debug/source tool in Chrome I can see that jquery.form.js IS being downloaded (it's listed on the "Scripts" tab).

Comment: IE9 says pretty much the same: the script file IS downloading, and the error that it comes up with is "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: You may have to change your script then so it gets called on page load:  $(document).ready(function () { ...code...});

That way the form will have the function prototyped correctly if the plug-in is installed.  Otherwise I would look into your script, because that should work.

Comment: I've copied the entire jquery.form plugin script and pasted it into a <script> element on the page. Same situation - error message still appears. So downloading the file isn't the root of the issue, but somehow the script isn't being loaded. I've re-downloaded the file to ensure that I haven't missed a closing brace or anything like that, but I still have the problem.

Comment: Is it stored locally?  If so it may be a permissions issue.

Comment: Yes, it's stored locally. When you say "permissions issue" do you mean this might be preventing it from downloading? If so then I can see that the script does download to the browser. Maybe there could be a permissions issue with the upload, but this issue relates to the client-side javascript engine apparently not being able to locate the function... or maybe I'm thinking along the wrong lines.

Comment: It would prevent downloading so you wouldn't be able to see the code from the browser.  If that's happening properly it has to be a problem with the javascript.

Comment: @wajiw This already is using the `ready` function - `$(function(){...})` is identical to `$(document).ready(function(){...})`.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut:

```
$(function () {
```

Doesn't work in latest version of jQuery, have to use:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
```

Comment: That's helpful to know, but I wouldn't be getting the error on page load if "$(function(){" wasn't working in the version I'm using. Nonetheless, thanks for the tip, and I have now changed it.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. I have 1.7.2 and this works without any errors.

Comment: At the time of writing it was true of the latest version

Comment: Hmm. I didn't notice the date-stamp. If you edit your question I can remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have the **$**

`$('#your-form')`

and not

`('#your-form')`