# Jquery ajax file upload not working

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use Ajax to do file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543926/is-it-possible-to-use-ajax-to-do-file-upload)

I'm trying to upload the image using jquery ajax.I used Jquery Load function.  I checked from firebug all the input fields are submitted except the image field that is type=file.

```
 CakePhp Code
    echo $this->Form->input('Testimonial.photo', array('type'=>'file', 'label'=>'Upload Avator'));

 Jquery Function
    $('a[rel=save]').live('click',function(clickEvent) {
            clickEvent.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#block").load(url, $("#form :input").serializeArray(),function(){
                }
            );
        });
```

How can i overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input type="file"` elements cannot be transferred using regular jQuery Ajax. You should take a look at the new File API in combination with "XMLHttpRequest level 2" that (unfortunately) is not supported by all modern browsers yet.

Workaround: iframe or Flash solutions (search for "uploadify" for example).

Comment: FYI, Uploadify can be difficult to implement if you have authentication in your site because sessions are not picked up by it and passed through by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [jQuery form](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugin.