# How to pass on a file from jQuery to phpMailer as an attachment?

Tags: php, jquery, submit, phpmailer, file-io

```
$(".feedback input.sent").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $(".feedback textarea.name").val();
  var mail = $(".feedback textarea.mail").val();
  var phone = $("feedback textarea.phone").val();
  // the file field probably has to be here somewhere as well?
  var info = $(".feedback textarea.info").val();

  if (name && mail && info) {
    var data = {name: name, mail: mail, phone: phone, info: info};
    // I guess I need to somehow get the file itself to this array to pass it to phpMailer?

    $.post(baseUrl + "templates/feedback.php", data, function() {
      $(".contact-form input, .contact-form textarea").val("");
        console.log("great");
    });
  }
  else {
    console.log("not great");
  }
});
```

Obviously I need to add multiple attachments, but I do not know how to pass them to the `$mail->AddAttachment($target_path);` which is what I need help with.

I am using [this](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to add multiple files.

My phpMailer works well until I add the AddAttachment() there, then it won't send an e-mail. I added a link for a picture there for example. It doesn't give me any errors as well, which is why I came here.

My primary need is still passing the what ever file(s) it is from the form to my feedback.php file, where the mailer does it's thing and attaching it/them all to the e-mail.

feedback.php file:

```
<?php

require_once "phpmailer.inc.php";

if ($_POST['name'] && $_POST['info']) {
  $message = "";
  $message .= "Name:\n" . $_POST['name'] . "\n\n";
  $message .= "E-Mail:\n" . $_POST['mail'] . "\n\n";
  $message .= "Phone:\n" . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n";
  $message .= "Message:\n" . $_POST['info'] . "\n\n";

  $mail = new PHPMailer();

  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->Host     = "xxx.xxx.xxx";

  $mail->Port     = 25;

  $mail->From     = "xxx@xxx.xxx";

  $mail->AddAddress("xxx@xxx.xxx");


  foreach($_FILES as $key => $file){
    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $target_path = $target_path .basename($file['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "the file ".basename($file['name'])." has been uploaded";
    }
    else {
     echo "there was an error";
    }
    $mail->AddAttachment($target_path);
  }

  $mail->Subject  = "Feedback";
  $mail->Body     = $message;
  $mail->WordWrap = 50;

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Error.';
    echo 'Problem: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
    echo 'Good';
  }

}

?>
```

I am really not sure about the Attachment part there, I found it from here somewhere, but using it without the fancy loop doesn't work as well...

Comment: It's not possible to send uploads via ajax. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543926/is-it-possible-to-use-ajax-to-do-file-upload

Comment: please post code for "templates/feedback.php"

Comment: @phpisuber01  you can serialize attachments and post them via ajax

Comment: use $_FILES in php to get the file data into a temp file and send it as a mail attachment.